# error while trying to install tesserocr

Tags: python-tesseract

I keep getting the same error when I try to install

```
(env) vagrant@vagrant:~$ pip install tesserocr
Collecting tesserocr
  Using cached tesserocr-2.1.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tesserocr ... error
  Complete output from command /home/vagrant/src/env/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4K2D6A/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmp5p5G1lpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Failed to extract tesseract version from executable: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  Supporting tesseract v3.04.00
  Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 197632}}
  cythoning tesserocr.pyx to tesserocr.cpp
  building 'tesserocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
  tesserocr.cpp:446:34: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
Failed to build tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
    Complete output from command /home/vagrant/src/env/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4K2D6A/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mePzAW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vagrant/src/env/include/site/python2.7/tesserocr:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    Failed to extract tesseract version from executable: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    Supporting tesseract v3.04.00
    Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 197632}}
    skipping 'tesserocr.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
    tesserocr.cpp:446:34: fatal error: leptonica/allheaders.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/vagrant/src/env/bin/python2 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-4K2D6A/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mePzAW-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/vagrant/src/env/include/site/python2.7/tesserocr" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4K2D6A/tesserocr/
```

Sachin System Error:

```
pip install tesserocr                                                                                     
Collecting tesserocr
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached tesserocr-2.1.3.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for tesserocr ... error
  Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YcBV5a/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpRrPD1Vpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  pkg-config failed to find tesseract/lep libraries: Package tesseract was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `tesseract.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'tesseract' found

  Supporting tesseract v3.03
  Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 771}}
  cythoning tesserocr.pyx to tesserocr.cpp
  building 'tesserocr' extension
  creating build
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
  cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_14PyPageIterator_20SetBoundingBoxComponents(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyPageIterator*, bool, bool)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:4622:25: error: ‘class tesseract::PageIterator’ has no member named ‘SetBoundingBoxComponents’
     __pyx_v_self->_piter->SetBoundingBoxComponents(__pyx_v_include_upper_dots, __pyx_v_include_lower_dots);
                           ^
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_14PyPageIterator_34GetImage(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyPageIterator*, tesseract::PageIteratorLevel, int, PyObject*)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:5854:125: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::PageIterator::GetImage(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel&, int&, Pix*&, int*, int*)’
     __pyx_v_pix = __pyx_v_self->_piter->GetImage(__pyx_v_level, __pyx_v_padding, __pyx_v_opix, (&__pyx_v_left), (&__pyx_v_top));
                                                                                                                               ^
  tesserocr.cpp:5854:125: note: candidate is:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:456:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/pageiterator.h:239:8: note: Pix* tesseract::PageIterator::GetImage(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel, int, int*, int*) const
     Pix* GetImage(PageIteratorLevel level, int padding,
          ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/pageiterator.h:239:8: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI_74AnalyseLayout(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, bool)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:16256:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AnalyseLayout(bool&)’
     __pyx_v_piter = __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.AnalyseLayout(__pyx_v_merge_similar_words);
                                                                                     ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16256:83: note: candidate is:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:461:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:489:17: note: tesseract::PageIterator* tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AnalyseLayout()
     PageIterator* AnalyseLayout();
                   ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:489:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:16600:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, bool&)’
         __pyx_t_2 = new tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_font_info);
                                                                                          ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16600:88: note: candidates are:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:175:3: note: tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer()
     TessHOcrRenderer();
     ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:175:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:173:16: note: tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer(const tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessHOcrRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:173:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  tesserocr.cpp:16643:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
         __pyx_t_3 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                            ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16643:106: note: candidates are:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:188:3: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*)
     TessPDFRenderer(const char *datadir);
     ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:188:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
  tesserocr.cpp:16727:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
         __pyx_t_4 = new tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                       ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16727:69: note: candidates are:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:227:3: note: tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer()
     TessUnlvRenderer();
     ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:227:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:225:16: note: tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer(const tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessUnlvRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:225:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer&’
  tesserocr.cpp:16811:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
         __pyx_t_5 = new tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                          ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16811:72: note: candidates are:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:238:3: note: tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer()
     TessBoxTextRenderer();
     ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:238:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:236:16: note: tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer(const tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessBoxTextRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:236:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer&’
  tesserocr.cpp:16895:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
         __pyx_t_6 = new tesseract::TessTextRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                       ^
  tesserocr.cpp:16895:69: note: candidates are:
  In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:164:3: note: tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer()
     TessTextRenderer();
     ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:164:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:162:16: note: tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer(const tesseract::TessTextRenderer&)
   class TESS_API TessTextRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                  ^
  /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:162:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessTextRenderer&’
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI_108IsValidCharacter(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, PyObject*)’:
  tesserocr.cpp:19661:60: error: ‘class tesseract::TessBaseAPI’ has no member named ‘IsValidCharacter’
     __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(__pyx_v_self->_baseapi.IsValidCharacter(__pyx_t_2)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2161, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                              ^
  tesserocr.cpp:544:36: note: in definition of macro ‘__Pyx_PyBool_FromLong’
   #define __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(b) ((b) ? __Pyx_NewRef(Py_True) : __Pyx_NewRef(Py_False))
                                      ^
  tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘void inittesserocr()’:
  tesserocr.cpp:25014:67: error: ‘PSM_RAW_LINE’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
     __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_PageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_RAW_LINE); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 132, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                     ^
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for tesserocr
  Running setup.py clean for tesserocr
Failed to build tesserocr
Installing collected packages: tesserocr
  Running setup.py install for tesserocr ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YcBV5a/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KHSvyq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    pkg-config failed to find tesseract/lep libraries: Package tesseract was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `tesseract.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'tesseract' found

    Supporting tesseract v3.03
    Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 771}}
    skipping 'tesserocr.cpp' Cython extension (up-to-date)
    building 'tesserocr' extension
    creating build
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/tesserocr.o
    cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_14PyPageIterator_20SetBoundingBoxComponents(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyPageIterator*, bool, bool)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:4622:25: error: ‘class tesseract::PageIterator’ has no member named ‘SetBoundingBoxComponents’
       __pyx_v_self->_piter->SetBoundingBoxComponents(__pyx_v_include_upper_dots, __pyx_v_include_lower_dots);
                             ^
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_14PyPageIterator_34GetImage(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyPageIterator*, tesseract::PageIteratorLevel, int, PyObject*)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:5854:125: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::PageIterator::GetImage(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel&, int&, Pix*&, int*, int*)’
       __pyx_v_pix = __pyx_v_self->_piter->GetImage(__pyx_v_level, __pyx_v_padding, __pyx_v_opix, (&__pyx_v_left), (&__pyx_v_top));
                                                                                                                                 ^
    tesserocr.cpp:5854:125: note: candidate is:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:456:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/pageiterator.h:239:8: note: Pix* tesseract::PageIterator::GetImage(tesseract::PageIteratorLevel, int, int*, int*) const
       Pix* GetImage(PageIteratorLevel level, int padding,
            ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/pageiterator.h:239:8: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI_74AnalyseLayout(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, bool)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:16256:83: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AnalyseLayout(bool&)’
       __pyx_v_piter = __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.AnalyseLayout(__pyx_v_merge_similar_words);
                                                                                       ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16256:83: note: candidate is:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:461:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:489:17: note: tesseract::PageIterator* tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AnalyseLayout()
       PageIterator* AnalyseLayout();
                     ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/baseapi.h:489:17: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘tesseract::TessResultRenderer* __pyx_f_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI__get_renderer(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, __pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:16600:88: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, bool&)’
           __pyx_t_2 = new tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_font_info);
                                                                                            ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16600:88: note: candidates are:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:175:3: note: tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer()
       TessHOcrRenderer();
       ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:175:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:173:16: note: tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer::TessHOcrRenderer(const tesseract::TessHOcrRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessHOcrRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:173:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    tesserocr.cpp:16643:106: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&, const char*)’
           __pyx_t_3 = new tesseract::TessPDFRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase, __pyx_v_self->_baseapi.GetDatapath());
                                                                                                              ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16643:106: note: candidates are:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:188:3: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const char*)
       TessPDFRenderer(const char *datadir);
       ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:188:3: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note: tesseract::TessPDFRenderer::TessPDFRenderer(const tesseract::TessPDFRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessPDFRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:186:16: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
    tesserocr.cpp:16727:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
           __pyx_t_4 = new tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                         ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16727:69: note: candidates are:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:227:3: note: tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer()
       TessUnlvRenderer();
       ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:227:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:225:16: note: tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer::TessUnlvRenderer(const tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessUnlvRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:225:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessUnlvRenderer&’
    tesserocr.cpp:16811:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
           __pyx_t_5 = new tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                            ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16811:72: note: candidates are:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:238:3: note: tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer()
       TessBoxTextRenderer();
       ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:238:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:236:16: note: tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer::TessBoxTextRenderer(const tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessBoxTextRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:236:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessBoxTextRenderer&’
    tesserocr.cpp:16895:69: error: no matching function for call to ‘tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer(__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t*&)’
           __pyx_t_6 = new tesseract::TessTextRenderer(__pyx_v_outputbase);
                                                                         ^
    tesserocr.cpp:16895:69: note: candidates are:
    In file included from tesserocr.cpp:459:0:
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:164:3: note: tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer()
       TessTextRenderer();
       ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:164:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:162:16: note: tesseract::TessTextRenderer::TessTextRenderer(const tesseract::TessTextRenderer&)
     class TESS_API TessTextRenderer : public TessResultRenderer {
                    ^
    /usr/include/tesseract/renderer.h:162:16: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘__pyx_t_9tesseract_cchar_t* {aka const char*}’ to ‘const tesseract::TessTextRenderer&’
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_13PyTessBaseAPI_108IsValidCharacter(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyTessBaseAPI*, PyObject*)’:
    tesserocr.cpp:19661:60: error: ‘class tesseract::TessBaseAPI’ has no member named ‘IsValidCharacter’
       __pyx_t_1 = __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(__pyx_v_self->_baseapi.IsValidCharacter(__pyx_t_2)); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 2161, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                ^
    tesserocr.cpp:544:36: note: in definition of macro ‘__Pyx_PyBool_FromLong’
     #define __Pyx_PyBool_FromLong(b) ((b) ? __Pyx_NewRef(Py_True) : __Pyx_NewRef(Py_False))
                                        ^
    tesserocr.cpp: In function ‘void inittesserocr()’:
    tesserocr.cpp:25014:67: error: ‘PSM_RAW_LINE’ is not a member of ‘tesseract’
       __pyx_t_2 = __Pyx_PyInt_From_enum__tesseract_3a__3a_PageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_RAW_LINE); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_2)) __PYX_ERR(0, 132, __pyx_L1_error)
                                                                       ^
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-YcBV5a/tesserocr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KHSvyq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-YcBV5a/tesserocr/
```

Answer (score 19):

Faced this problem today. It happens because we are missing these system libraries (which must be installed *before* you run `pip install tesserocr`):

> libleptonica-dev and libtesseract-dev

Solution is to install them using your package manager.

- Ubuntu

  - `apt-get install libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev`
- Mac

  - `pip install tesserocr`

    - will auto install `tesserocr` and its dependent lib `leptonica`

solved the issue

Comment: What issue/error are you getting after doing what i suggested, and what is your platform?

Comment: i am using ubuntu on cloud9. see updated error above.

Comment: Try installing python-dev package, maybe you are missing headers

Comment: If installation of above libraries does not help please install pkg-config as well - it worked for me.

Comment: This helped me too, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My error was like:

```
Failed building wheel for tesserocr
(...)
Supporting tesseract v4.0.0
Building with configs: {'libraries': ['tesseract', 'lept'], 'cython_compile_time_env': {'TESSERACT_VERSION': 67108864}}
(...)
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c tesserocr.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/tesserocr.o -std=c++11 -DUSE_STD_NAMESPACE
tesserocr.cpp: In function 'PyObject* __pyx_pf_9tesserocr_16PyResultIterator_8GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices(__pyx_obj_9tesserocr_PyResultIterator*)':
tesserocr.cpp:12192:43: error: 'class tesseract::ResultIterator' has no member named 'GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices'

   __pyx_v_output = (__pyx_v_self->_riter->GetBestLSTMSymbolChoices()[0]);
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-s6f5ze1q/tesserocr/setup.py';
  f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))"
  install --record /tmp/pip-lopr6cjz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile"

failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-s6f5ze1q/tesserocr/
```

I resolved it with additional installation of **pkg-config** library.

```
apt-get install libleptonica-dev libtesseract-dev \
    tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng \
    pkg-config
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a linux(Debian based like Ubuntu 14.04) system you would like to upgrade your Tesseract version. Apparently in Ubuntu 14.04 default Tesseract version is 3.03 which is not supported by tesserocr. You have to build from source with some newer Tesseract versions like 4.00 or 3.05.But in newer OS versions this should not be a problem.

**Just follow the link for the installation**
[Installing Tesserocr with Tesseract 3.04+](https://medium.com/@lucas63/installing-tesseract-3-04-in-ubuntu-14-04-1dae8b748a32)