# Cannot install tesserocr

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I try running `pip install tesserocr` and I get the following error...

> error: 'cinttypes' file not found
>     #include   // PRId32, ...
>              ^~~~~~~~~~~
>     1 error generated.
>     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---
>
> Failed building wheel for tesserocr

I've searched the entire web. I even tried compiling the source code and then running `pip install .` but this gave me the exact same error. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various questions like this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43486636/error-while-trying-to-install-tesserocr).
tesserocr is compiled during installation so you have to install also the development packages needed.
Which these are depends on your OS distribution